# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'blit'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, blit

I am making a flappy bird game A.I, using pygame and neat following a tutorial series  [Tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ps55secj7iU&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-lwGZWXz5Qgta_YNX3_vLS2&index=2), and I am getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\flappy_bird.py", line 108, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\flappy_bird.py", line 104, in main
    draw_window(win, bird)
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\flappy_bird.py", line 87, in draw_window
    Bird.draw(bin)
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\flappy_bird.py", line 79, in draw
    win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import neat
import os
import time
import random

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\imgs", "bird3.png")))]
PIPE_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\imgs", "pipe.png")))]
BASE_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\imgs", "base.png")))]
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\imgs", "bg.png")))

class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y 
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y
    
    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2
        
        self.y = self.y + d
        
        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION

        else: 
            if self.tilt >-90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    # This draw function deals with flapping of wings animation.
    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img_count = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img_count = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img_count = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            self.img_count = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2     

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)       
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)


def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

def draw_window(win, Bird):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, BG_IMG.get_rect())
    Bird.draw(bin)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    bird = Bird(200, 200)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        Bird.move
        draw_window(win, bird)

    

main()
```

Comment: I'd guess you have to *call* that function or method, e.g. `win(...).blit(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo, you've written `Bird.draw(bin)` instead of `Bird.draw(win)` in your *draw_window* function.

This function should be like that:

```py
def draw_window(win, Bird):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, BG_IMG.get_rect())
    Bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: it just throws another error after making the changes 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'pygame.Surface' and 'int''

Comment: the full error is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\flappy_bird.py", line 108, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\flappy_bird.py", line 104, in main
    draw_window(win, bird)
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\flappy_bird.py", line 87, in draw_window
    Bird.draw(win)
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\PYTHON\Flappy bird AI\flappy_bird.py", line 59, in draw
    self.img_count += 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'pygame.Surface' and 'int'`

Comment: maybe you would tell where can we discuss  @Vinegret43